# Access SSL-Parameters in connections via Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, ssl, jdbc, sessionfactory

I am using a hibernate java application which uses a sessionfactory to create connections and sessions. As i am using it with a postgresql database i pass the proper jdbc connectionstring to build the sessionfactory and get my sessions from it afterwards. The only thing im able to access is the jdbc4connection.

**How am i able to read which ciphersuite is used within the secured connection, which SSL protocol is used etc?**

Here is how i initialize my sessionfactory:

```
Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
Properties p = configuration.getProperties();
p.setProperty("hibernate.connection.url","jdbc:postgresql://127.0.0.1:5432/postgres?ssl=true&sslfactory=org.postgresql.ssl.NonValidatingFactory");
p.setProperty("hibernate.connection.username", "myusername");
p.setProperty("hibernate.connection.password", "mypassword");
p.setProperty("hibernate.connection.driver_class",
            "org.postgresql.Driver");
p.setProperty("hibernate.dialect",
            "org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect");
ServiceRegistry serviceRegistryWebOnkys = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder()
            .applySettings(p).build();
SessionFactory sessionFactory = configuration
            .buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistryWebOnkys);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can find out how to do it with via regular JDBC  (I don't know how it's done), then you can do the same thing with Hibernate.

```
session.doWork(new Work() {
    @Override
    public void execute(Connection connection) throws SQLException {
        // access the connection here and perform regular jdbc operations.
    }
});
```

This is what I had to do when I had set some Oracle specific properties that could be set only on "OracleConnection.java" instances.

```
oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleConnection oc = (oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleConnection) connection.getMetaData().getConnection()
```

Comment: I am not able to do it via regular JDBC Connection though. I need access to the connected SSLSocketFactory.

Comment: Try turning on TRACE level loggin for postgres package. It may give some pointers about what to do.